# How to stop Windows from killing a 'unresponsive' game?

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I play a sports simulation game called Eastside Hockey Manager, where as the name implies you manage a hockey team. Whenever you finish a day, the game starts to process everything that's happening, the most labour intensive part of the game, and with a lot of stuff loaded in the game it can take from anywhere between 5 to 60+ seconds.

All is fine, but since I got it windowed I like to alt-tab out and do something else in the meantime. But the issue is, that whenever I do so Windows eventually regards the game as unresponsive and kills the application or gives me the whole 'send bug report' nonsense.

I know for a fact the game hasn't locked up or crashed, because the easiest fix is to never tab out of the game and wait out the processing period, but due to the times involved that kinda ruins my ability to multi-task since processing is done often.

The game itself being unresponsive is a part of it, because it focuses all its efforts on just processing and you can't do anything in the game until it's finished.

So I was wondering, is there a way to prevent windows from regarding the application as unresponsive, to not prompt me and just let the app do its thing until it's finished?

As per the comments the actual error message I'm seeing is the following:

[image: error message screenshot]

edit:

The error message as read from the event log...
https://pastebin.com/b3FL2w4A

As mentioned earlier though, it only happens because I tab out of the game whilst it's processing. Tabbing in/out when it's just idle won't give me the issues, as does just keeping the window active throughout its processing.

Comment: Windows does not kill unresponsive applications unless you select to do so. It may display a prompt though.

Comment: It also doesn't give me a prompt to ignore it and let it run its course. It only gives me the option to close the application.

Comment: Just don't press close. Just ignore it - and when the application resumes / finishes what its doing, the prompt is usually disappears by itself. (This is anecdotal - and I have seen this happens a lot when I was using HDD. Moving to SSD practically make that never to happen)

Comment: Not for me, it just gives me the prompt that it doesn't work anymore and gives me the button to close the programme. 

https://i.imgur.com/jwv2RFU.png

That's it, I also can't just let it stand there and tab to the programme because then it still just shows me the prompt and forces me to close it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that's not the dialog for an unresponsive process but rather a process that actually encountered an error. As for figuring out why the Event Log might have some information or the game might write some kind of crash log.

Comment: Hello Seth, I have added the event to my main post.